# Android: Computing the needed View object size

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I need help approaching this problem I encountered just starting my project. I need to display three squares (View objects) across the screen and several down the screen. My problem is I don't want to hard code the pixel size of those View objects; I would just like to compute the size that each square needs to be. I know it's impossible to pass data into an XML file from a java file, so that possible solution of calculating the size in a java file then passing that information into the XML file is out. Could anyone help me with a possible solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "pass" the data to the XML file.
Each XML element has it's instance object that can be accessed.
Checkout the "findById" method: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: So I can get access to the root View object (the entire screen) then compute the dimensions that the child View objects need to be? But wouldn't I then need to create those child View objects in the actual Java file instead of creating them in the xml file? I've heard creating UI elements in Java wasn't very stable.

Comment: I don't where you heard that creating them in the xml file is not so stable. Most of the UI is created by the XML. In your case, you can create the XML, then, get the instance using the View.findById method, and then re-calculate the size.